# Soyuz 11 - communication transcript

Tags: history, soyuz-spacecraft

Are there any communication transcripts available of Soyuz 11 spaceflight? I am especially interested in the part where pressure equalisation valve was opened way too fast and the crew died due to asphyxiation.

Comment: I'll second that motion!

Comment: No. About 10 years ago, I spoke with a veteran of Soviet cosmonautics. She worked as the chief telemetrist. According to her, no one understood what happened. And when they understood it, it was too late.

Comment: Have a look at https://forum.novosti-kosmonavtiki.ru/index.php?topic=9779.0 The very first message contains  (yellow on white :-) the final exchange transcript. Immediately before going to the atmosphere re-entry blackout. The google translation is kinda intelligible. There were no recordings of intra-vehicular communications, afaict, only telemetry.